# no access to Users & Permissions

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, permissions

i don't have access anymore to the features site permissions & access request and invitations  on the Site Settings Page. neither to i see the option Site collection administrator

Can you tell me how to proceed to give permissions to our members?

thanks

Comment: First of all check the permissions you are having on site collection level. To give permissions to another users, you will be needing the site collection administrator(or full control) access on site collection.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you dont have Site collection administrator rights on your site collection. If you have full control on the site collection then you can see access request option by going >`site settings > User and permissions > Access Requests and Invitations.`

easy workaround, I think, 1st you need to fix your permission. Ask your administrators / owner of the sites, added your id into site collection administrator group. this will put you back on old level where you can do everything.

for access request, read this [support article from MSFT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-up-and-manage-access-requests-94B26E0B-2822-49D4-929A-8455698654B3)